# Mask out sensitive information in python log

Tags: python, security, logging, python-logging

Consider the following code

```
try:
    r = requests.get('https://sensitive:passw0rd@what.ever/')
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.HTTPError:
    logging.exception("Failed to what.ever")
```

Here, if the endpoint returns non-successful http status code, the following will be logged

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 5, in <module>
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 928, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://sensitive:passw0rd@what.ever/
```

The problem is that the *password* is logged. I could create a logging filter to filter out this line completely. However, it would be more convenient if the password was just masked out somehow. As no string is passed to `logging.exception` filtering on the app side is tricky. Where in the logging framwork can I transform a log record?

Comment: Is that url a magic value or did you create the url from some variables?

Comment: It's a magic actually, but if you've got suggestions either way I'm all ears. 

Comment: Related: [Hiding Sensitive Data from Logs with Python](https://www.relaxdiego.com/2014/07/logging-in-python.html)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently, this is done with a `Formatter`. Example below

```
import logging
import re


class SensitiveFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """Formatter that removes sensitive information in urls."""
    @staticmethod
    def _filter(s):
        return re.sub(r':\/\/(.*?)\@', r'://', s)

    def format(self, record):
        original = logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
        return self._filter(original)
```

Use like so

```
import logging
import requests

from sensitive_formatter import SensitiveFormatter

LOG_FORMAT = \
    '%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-16s] %(filename)27s:%(lineno)-4d %(levelname)7s| %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Don't actually configure your logging like this, just to showcase
# the above answer. :)
for handler in logging.root.handlers:
   handler.setFormatter(SensitiveFormatter(LOG_FORMAT))

log.warning('https://not:shown@httpbin.org/basic-auth/expected-user/expected-pass')
try:
    r = requests.get('https://not:shown@httpbin.org/basic-auth/expected-user/expected-pass')
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    log.exception('boom!')
```

The user/password will be masked out. See example log below

```
$ python log_example.py 
2018-05-18 11:59:22,703 [MainThread      ]                      log.py:14   WARNING| https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/secret
2018-05-18 11:59:22,747 [MainThread      ]           connectionpool.py:824    DEBUG| Starting new HTTPS connection (1): httpbin.org
2018-05-18 11:59:23,908 [MainThread      ]           connectionpool.py:396    DEBUG| https://httpbin.org:443 "DELETE /basic-auth/user/secret HTTP/1.1" 405 178
2018-05-18 11:59:23,913 [MainThread      ]                      log.py:19     ERROR| boom!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log.py", line 17, in <module>
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/vidstige/src/so/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 405 Client Error: METHOD NOT ALLOWED for url: https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/secret
```

Comment: Can you show what the error log looks like with the password masked out?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro absolutely

Comment: Can `SensitiveFormatter` also be instantiated without argument?

Comment: Yes, it can. Then the default value of `&#39;%(message)s` will be used.