# How to mask the credentials in the Airflow logs?

Tags: airflow

I want to make sure some of the encrypted variables does not appear in airflow log.
I am passing AWS keys to Exasol Export sql, in the Airflow log it is getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not possible out-of-the-box. You can, however, configure your own Python Logger and use that class by changing `logging_config_class` property in `airflow.cfg` file.

Example here: [Mask out sensitive information in python log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380452/mask-out-sensitive-information-in-python-log)

Answer (score 0):

Are the AWS keys sent as part of the data for SQL export or are they sent for the connection?

If they are sent for connection, then hiding these credentials is possible. You simply would have to create a connection and send export the data from the connection.