# Apache Airflow Bash Operator with environment variable

Tags: bash, airflow

I have environment variable configured in /etc/sysconfig/airflow

```
PASSWORD=pass123
```

I am hoping to be able to use this in the Bash command within BashOperator so that the password will not be visible in the Airflow UI or log. The variable will then be used in the DAG task as below.

```
con = 'username/$PASSWORD@//ex01-db.mybiz.com:1521/dwh'

sqlcl_cmd = f"""/oracle/sqlcl/bin/sql -s {con} > /data/tmp/extract.csv <<EOF
SET SQLFORMAT CSV
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SELECT * FROM ORDER.DAILY_SALES;
EXIT
EOF
"""

BashOperator(
    task_id = 'extract_order',
    bash_command = sqlcl_cmd,
    dag = dag
)
```

However, it's observed that the variable `$PASSWORD` is not expanded by Bash, resulting in error. How do I correctly use environment variable to be passed to `bash_command` in BashOperator.

Comment: You probably need to remove the spaces around the `=` operator in the assignation of `con='...'` (first line of code) and write `${con}` instead of `{con}` in your script.

Comment: If you are running with systemd, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195896/airflow-configuration-in-environment-variable-not-working?

If you are not running with systemd, https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html#storing-variables-in-environment-variables?

does this help?

Comment: @Emma that will hide the password for Airflow UI for the code, but it will still be visible in the log

Comment: env variable will show in logs. Masking in logs is not an out-of-the-box feature but can work around.  Here is the work around example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380452/mask-out-sensitive-information-in-python-log.

Otherwise, I guess you would need aws kms kind of things.

Comment: The original question was env variable is not expanding. If you would like to ask about masking in logs, I would suggest you to edit the title and description.

Answer (score 0):

First, test out if your airflow user has access to that variable. 'echo $PASSWORD'. You can change the $PASSWORD temporarily if you do not want to show that in the log.

If it does then you can pass the con with a parameter in the bash task as you can see it here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.2/tutorial.html

```
con = 'username/$PASSWORD@//ex01-db.mybiz.com:1521/dwh'

sqlcl_cmd = f"""/oracle/sqlcl/bin/sql -s {{params.con}} > /data/tmp/extract.csv <<EOF
SET SQLFORMAT CSV
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SELECT * FROM ORDER.DAILY_SALES;
EXIT
EOF
"""

BashOperator(
    task_id = 'extract_order',
    params={'con': con},
    bash_command = sqlcl_cmd,
    dag = dag
)
```